# C - Comparing two characters

Tags: c, compare, character

I am having trouble comparing two characters. I've written a very basic C problem to try out command line arguments.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char ch;
    char *type = "";
    char *gender = "";
    int baby = 0;
    int count = 0;

    /* Options:
     * -t = type of pet
     * -g = gender
     * -b = baby or adult
     */
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "t:g:b")) != EOF)
        switch (ch) {
            case 't':
                type = optarg;
                break;
            case 'g':
                gender = optarg;
                break;
            case 'b':
                baby = 1;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid option.\n");
                return 1;
        }

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    printf("You have chosen a %s.\n", type);
    if (gender == 'f')
        puts("It's a girl");
    if (gender == 'b')
        puts("It's a boy.");

    // The main command line arguments should be about the traits of the pet
    printf("%s", "Traits: ");
    for (count = 0; count < argc; count++)
        printf("%s ", argv[count]);

    return 0;
}
```

So if I type this into the terminal:

```
  $ ./pet_shop -t dog -g f cute small
```

I get this as output:

```
  You have chosen a dog:
  Traits: cute small
```

The output it missing information about the gender, it should be a girl since I entered f. But I tried checking by printf("%i", gender) which gave the value 0. Is g == 'f' the incorrect way of comparing two characters?

Comment: Definitions such as `char *type = "";` are read only i.e. you cannot directly assign strings to `type` once you've declared it. Have a read through this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kc54dd5(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings (e.g. with GCC's `-Wall`) and errors like this will easily be found.

Comment: @Nobilis: You can certainly assign things to `type`. You can't write into the pointed-to value but OP is not doing that.

Comment: @Nobilis: that would be true for a `char *const`.

Comment: @larsmans `char * ptr = ""` are still read only in C :)
@interjay yes, sorry, `optarg` is a pointer here right?

Comment: @Nobilis: they are not. String literals are read-only, `char*` variables aren't.

Comment: @Nobilis: I mean that a `char*` variable can be reassigned to point somewhere else, and that is what the OP does. The strings pointed to should not be and are not modified by the posted program.

Comment: @larsmans okay, I thought you meant that the read only segment could be modified by a 'char *'. I raised it because of my assumption that  the OP intended to use `char* type` in a way similar to a character array. Then only later did I realise that optarg is a pointer so all's good.

Comment: ch should be declared as `int`, otherwise `EOF` handling might not be correct ion some platforms.

Comment: Actually `getopt` does not return `EOF`, it returns `-1`. (Same value, different concepts.)

Answer (score 16):

`gender` is a `char*`, i.e. a pointer to a string's first charadcter. When you compare that to a single `char`, both the `char` and the pointer are converted to integers and an integer comparison is done.

To compare strings, use `strcmp` from `<string.h>`:

```
if (strcmp(gender, "f") == 0)
    // it's a girl
```

Note the double quote (`"`) which signifies a string, rather than a single character.

Comment: Strcmp is a bit...overkill to compare a single character

Comment: @slugonamission: it's much easier to write than `gender[0] == 'f' && gender[1] == '\0'`. It will likely get inlined when used with a short string literal and performance isn't really critical in this program.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're comparing a string (or rather, a `char*`) to a `char`. This comparison (i.e. `if(gender == 'f')`) will compare the raw pointer value to the character instead of comparing the contents of the string to the character. Instead, you need to dereference the pointer and then compare that value, or index into the string, i.e. `if(gender[0] == 'f')`.

Of course, it would also be a good idea to check that the string actually contains something before attempting that in order to avoid a segfault.

Comment: This gives a false positive if `gender` is any string that starts with `'f'`.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
char *gender = "";
```

So `gender` is a string, not a character. To compare strings, use [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Comment: You did not explain why it is a string and not a character.

Answer (score 3):

You first declared gender as a string:

```
char *gender = "";
```

Then you later treat is as a single character:

```
if(gender == 'f')
   [...]
if(gender == 'b')
```

You need to clarify in your own mind what `gender` is, before you try and code it.
Pick one definition, and stick with it.